# Grammatical terms

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality

What is the grammatical term for *watering down a phrase so it makes it non-offensive*? For example, rather than 'rape' a newspaper may print 'assaulted' they wont use the offensive details but what is this technique called in English?

Comment: It's not a grammatical term, whatever it might be. Grammar doesn't have to do with "watering down" meaning; it has to do with putting words together, whatever their meaning.

Comment: @John Understatement? Litotes?

Comment: Those aren't grammatical; they're rhetorical.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a specific “English” technique, but there are several ways to describe this:

- *To **Bowdlerize*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bowdlerize), [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bowdlerize))

  > Origin
  >   Mid 19th century: from the name of Dr Thomas Bowdler (1754–1825), who published an expurgated edition of Shakespeare in 1818, + -ize. *[Oxford]*
- ***Political Correctness*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/politically-correct?q=political+correctness), [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/political_correctness)) — not so much the technique as the motive

  > A politically correct word or expression is used instead of another one to avoid being offensive *[Cambridge]*
- *To **Understate*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/understate))

  > to describe something in a way that makes it seem less important, serious, bad, etc. than it really is
- ***Euphemism*** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) — sorry!)

  > A ***euphemism /ˈjuːfəˌmɪzəm/*** is a **generally innocuous** word or expression used **in place of one that may be found offensive or suggest something unpleasant**.[1] Some euphemisms are intended to amuse; while others use **bland, inoffensive terms for things the user wishes to downplay**. Euphemisms are used **to refer to taboo topics** (such as disability, sex, excretion, and death) **in a polite way, or to mask profanity**.[2]

You can find a number of others by looking up ***downplay*** or ***water down*** and chasing around a thesaurus. One usually found in the negative is *[Don't] **mince** [one's] **words***.